# How to improve WordPress insert/update query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, performance, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am creating my own WordPress plugin that imports profiles as posts,and while the script works, I am looking to improve the query that inserts/updates the posts.

This script runs at every 5 minutes and works like this,

**1**.import/update all profiles from an external source in local *users* table. This is straightforward and works ok

**2**. Set all existing posts custom field *status* to offline before updating

```
$offline = "UPDATE $meta SET meta_value='offline' WHERE meta_key='status'";
```

**3**. Select from table *users* all profiles that are online

```
$new_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status='online' ORDER BY visitors DESC";
```

**4**. Foreach profile, if post exists,update, else create new post

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results($new_query);
foreach ($result as $post){
    $cat = $post->gender.'s';
    $getterm = get_term_by('name',$cat,'user-category');
    $cat_id = $getterm->term_id;
    $custfields = array (
        'name'          => $post->name,
        'age'           => $post->age,
        'subject'       => $post->subject,
        'status'        => $post->status,
        'fans'          => $post->fans,
        'visitors'      => $post->visitors,
    );
    endif;
    $postarr = array (
        'post_title'    => $post->username,
        'post_name'     => $post->username.'-profile',
        'post_content'  => 'something',
        'post_type'     => 'users-profile',
        'post_category' =>  array($cat_id),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',       
        'meta_input'    => $custfields
    );
    $postcheck = get_page_by_title($post->username,OBJECT, 'users-profile');    
    
    if($postcheck):
            update_post_meta($postcheck->ID ,'subject', $post->subject );
            update_post_meta($postcheck->ID ,'status', $post->status );
            update_post_meta($postcheck->ID ,'visitors', $post->visitors );
    else :
        wp_set_object_terms(wp_insert_post( $postarr,true),$cat_id,'user-category',true);
    endif;
}
```

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_users

wp_users    CREATE TABLE `wp_users` (
  `username` varchar(111) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gender` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `subject` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `languages` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `isnew` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `imagebig` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `fans` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `visitors` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timeonline` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `location` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta`

wp_postmeta CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=405678 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `wp_posts`

wp_posts    CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `ping_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `post_password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to_ping` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pinged` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content_filtered` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `guid` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `post_type` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  KEY `post_author` (`post_author`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=57991 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

What i am trying to do is, move the offline switch after the update/insert and apply it to all posts not in the SELECT statement...and maybe a better way of doing the update/insert.

Maybe something like this:

Select all online profiles from users table, select posts that matches the profiles (post title = profile username), if post exist update else create, switch offline the rest of the posts in table. Is this possible?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables.

Comment: Updated the question.Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix indexing (KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))) is an abomination.  Yes, it is a 'necessary' kludge due to `utf8mb4`.  But it is hurting you.  Do this

```
SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(meta_key)) from wp_postmeta;
```

If it comes back 191 or less, then change the size of meta_key to 191 and get rid of `(191)` in the index.  And see the other tips in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Those tips may be the solution to your Question.

`UPDATEing` a flag in lots of rows seems like a clumsy way to process things.  Isn't there a way to simply fold in the new data without the using the offline/online flag?  (I guess I am still missing the intent.)  If it is a million rows, that update may take a long time.

"all posts not in the SELECT" -- This sounds like a "multi-table UPDATE" statement.  It would involve a `LEFT JOIN ON ... WHERE ... IS NULL`.  Can you mock up a few rows with the important columns?  Show us the "before" and "after" of what should be in those tables.

You could also apply the above action to `post_name`.

> `age` int(11)

Do you run around incrementing that every year?

Comment: For what it's worth, Mr. James, there are millions upon millions of WordPress instances in the wild, each one of them with its `postmeta` table indexed exactly that way.

Comment: @O.Jones - Yeah.  The 191 was not needed before people started using utf8mb4 (introduced in MySQL 5.5).  And many of those millions need the performance boost in my blog.  I also posted the fix on the WP Q&A site, but it has not gotten much traction.  BTW, 5.7 eliminates the need for 191, but users will probably not remove the index prefixing.  :(

Comment: @RickJames i am looking to improve the performance, so i took your advice and removed meta_id from postmeta, also max(char_length) for meta_key was 27 so i changed the size to 55.

Comment: @k33n - and you changed the `PRIMARY KEY` to a composite key, I assume.

Comment: I use the online/ofline flag to show only the posts/profiles that are online, and i can't think of another way of how to achieve this. I agree that this update is taking a lot of time as it has to go trough all the existing posts which are now at 60k and growing.This is why i am researching how to optimize it, i am thinking of a combination of LEFT JOIN and subqueries to specify exactly which posts needs updating and which profiles needs insert but i am still wrapping my head around it. After the update/insert is done, the offline switch won't affect the overall performance that much, i guess

Comment: @RickJames if you mean this ``` ADD PRIMARY KEY(post_id, meta_key);``` yes, however this generated lots of database errors.

Comment: @k33n - An `UPDATE` of 60K rows will take a long time, regardless of how it is formulated.  "if post exists,update, else create new post" -- see if you can use IODKU for that step.  And maybe it will obviate the need for "offline".

Comment: ** WordPress database error Unknown column 'meta_id' in 'field list' for query SELECT meta_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'subject' AND post_id = 8453 made by update_post_meta, update_metadata;**  and for many others.

Comment: @k33n - Ok, read further down my link;  It explains how to keep `meta_id` but still get most of the performance improvement.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you very much for your answers. I did what you suggested and combined with a few query tweaks from your advice,the overall performance has increased a lot both front-end and back-end

Comment: @k33n - Thanks for reporting back.